# How to insert linebreaks in generated html code

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter to generate an html table for insertion into a template view. Unfortunately this is coming out as a very long string on 1 line like:

```
<table id="myDataTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="clear: both"><tbody><tr><td>id</td><td><a href="#" id="id" data-type="text" data-pk="2" data-url="/post" data-title="id">2</a></td></tr><tr><td>email</td><td><a href="#" id="email" data-type="text" data-pk="2" data-url="/post" data-title="email">A@B.COM</a></td></tr><br><tr><td>notes</td><td><a href="#" id="notes" data-type="text" data-pk="2" data-url="/post" data-title="notes">notes go here</a></td></tr><br> ...
```

I want it to look more like:

```
<tr>         
    <td>field1</td>
    <td><a href="#" id="field1" data-type="select" data-pk="1" data-value="" data-original-title="Select field1"></a></td>
    <td><span class="muted">Select, loaded from js array. Custom display</span></td>
</tr>

<tr>         
    <td>field2</td>
    <td><a href="#" id="field2" data-type="select" data-pk="1" data-value="" data-original-title="Select field2"></a></td>
    <td><span class="muted">Select, loaded from js array. Custom display</span></td>
</tr>
```

Here is my code:

```
$string='<table id="myDataTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="clear: both"><tbody>';

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $string=$string."<tr><td>$key</td>";  
    $element='<td><a href="#" id="'.$key.'" data-type="text" data-pk="'.$rowID.'" data-url="/post" data-title="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</a>'.'</td></tr>'."<br>";
    $string=$string.$element;
}

$string=$string.'</tbody></table>';
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why generate HTML with PHP? CodeIgniter allows you to separate your views, controllers and models, which helps you to keep PHP use in a view to a minimum. You could try `<td><?php echo $yourValue; ?></td>`. Using this, your could already indent most of your HTML in your view normally and you won't have to hassle with `\n\t`. What you're doing is not wrong, but to me, it seems to be going against CodeIgniter (and I personally find it rather ugly to generate HTML this way).

Comment: what difference does it make?... use a browser console if you want to inspect output, will all be organized into tree

Answer (score 2):

You can add newlines (`\n`) and tabs (`\t`) to your `$string` variable.

E.g.:

```
$string='<table id="myDataTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="clear: both">\n\t<tbody>\n';
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $string = $string."<tr>\n\t<td>$key</td>\n";  
    $element = '\t<td><a href="#" id="'.$key.'" data-type="text" data-pk="'
            .$rowID.'" data-url="/post" data-title="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</a>'
            .'</td>\n</tr>'."<br>";
    $string = $string.$element;
}
$string=$string.'\n\t</tbody>\n</table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `\n` and `\t` characters in your loop.

For example:

```
$string=$string."<tr>\n\t<td>$key</td>\n"; 
$element='\t<td><a href="#" id="'.$key.'" data-type="text" data-pk="'.$rowID.'" data-url="/post" data-title="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</a>'.'</td>\n</tr>'."<br>";
```

Also, you shouldn't have a line break after the `</tr>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the line breaks with \n and \t for tabs

```
$string='<table id="myDataTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="clear: both">\n\t<tbody>\n';

        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        $string=$string."\t\t<tr><td>$key</td>\n";  
        $element='\t\t<td><a href="#" id="'.$key.'" data-type="text" data-pk="'.$rowID.'" data-url="/post" data-title="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</a>'.'</td></tr>\n';
        $string=$string.$element;
        }


          $string=$string.'\t</tbody>\n</table>';
```

Also br tag is not allowed directly  inside table, so I removed it. It doesn't serve any purpose anyways since rows automatically appear on new lines

Answer (score 0):

You could add the line breaks with `\n` and `\t` to your `$string` variable:

```
$string='<table id="myDataTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="clear: both">\n\t<tbody>\n';

        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        $string=$string."\t\t<tr><td>$key</td>\n";  
        $element='\t\t<td><a href="#" id="'.$key.'" data-type="text" data-pk="'.$rowID.'" data-url="/post" data-title="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</a>'.'</td></tr>\n'."<br>";
        $string=$string.$element;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest experimenting with \n and spaces in the echoes, for example:

```
$string=$string."<tr>\n    <td>$key</td>";
```

I believe the result will be:

```
<tr>
    <td>field1</td>
```

Edit: Michael's response using \t and \n is way better.