# Strange linebreak characters showing up in my view

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter to generate an html table for insertion into a template view. With help from [How to insert linebreaks in generated html code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973702/how-to-insert-linebreaks-in-generated-html-code) and some experimentation, I have been able to change my code to:

```
$string='<table id="myDataTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="clear: both">\n <tbody>\n';

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

    $string=$string."\t\n<tr><td>$key</td>";  
    $element='<td><a href="#" id="'.$key.'" data-type="text" data-pk="'.$rowID.'" data-url="/post" data-title="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</a>'.'</td></tr>\n';
    $string=$string.$element;
    }
$string=$string.'</tbody>\n</table>';
```

I then inject this produced html string into my CI view which looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <base href="<?=base_url();?>">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Vitaliy Potapov">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
   <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.4.5/bootstrap-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


</head> 
<body> 


  <?=$html_string;?>  


  <script src='js/jquery.js'></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.4.5/bootstrap-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
$('#myDataTable').editable();
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
});

</script>

 </body> 
</html>
```

I am getting the expected table, nbut for some reason I see a bunch of generated new line charachters before the table when I look at the generated HTML.

```
     \n \n  
\n  
\n  
\n  
\n  
\n  
\n  
\n  
\n  
\n  
\n  
\n  
\n  
\n\n
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: probably because of `$string=`. You need to escape your `"` and use `$string="content with escaped double quotes etc";`

Comment: Yes. @Fred, as this is the answer, why not post it as an answer?

Comment: Try

$string="<table id=\"myDataTable\" class=\"table table-bordered table-striped\" style=\"clear: both\">\n <tbody>\n";

or 

$string="<table id='myDataTable' class='table table-bordered table-striped' style='clear: both'>\n <tbody>\n";

Comment: Oh, and they're displayed above the table because that's how most browsers handle this error (plain text in a table outside of any td): put it in front of all the content that is in tds. Don't ask me why, that's just what they do.

Comment: @MrLister Ok, I won't ask then lol! What I don't know, won't hurt me? lol let's hope not ;-) cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escaped characters are not interpolated when using single quotes. To fix this either remove the \n from the string or change your code to something like this:

```
<?php
$string='<table id="myDataTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="clear: both">'."\n".' <tbody>'."\n";

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

    $string=$string."\t\n<tr><td>$key</td>";  
    $element='<td><a href="#" id="'.$key.'" data-type="text" data-pk="'.$rowID.'" data-url="/post" data-title="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</a>'.'</td></tr>'."\n";
    $string=$string.$element;
}
$string=$string."</tbody>\n</table>";
```

Comment: Or use double quotes for the PHP string and single quotes for the HTML part.

Comment: @MrLister [interpolated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_interpolation) is the correct term

Comment: @shomz That would work as well, and there is a good argument for consistent quoting and escaping.

Answer (score 7):

## `EDIT

I gave an answer probably at the very same time as Orangepill, and then later edited my answer to give Orangepill credit.

---

## `Original answer:`

Probably because of `$string='';`

You need to escape your `"` inside (double-quotes), and use:
`$string="content with escaped double quotes etc";`

In this case, `$string` and all other variables must be enclosed inside of double quotation marks to be treated as a [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

As per [**Orangepill's**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17979582/1415724) answer, the use of concatenates is also a must.

- More on [**strings here**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) as per the PHP manual.
- You may also consult the PHP.net Web site on [**concatenates here**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).